# Sqlite accessing db function

Tags: c, xcode, sqlite

I'm using the function sqlite3_prepare_v2 to access to the database but it not returns SQLITE_ERROR( http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_abort.html ).I tried to use another db and it was ok.I made a new db(with navicat) the function returns SQLITE_ERROR...The code is ok,the problem regards the db.I thought to make the new db with the command line but where is saved?Any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest the error relates to the schema not matching the query, but I cannot give more detail until you do.

Comment: the query is right i'm sure

Comment: If it works on another database then it's the database that is wrong.

Comment: Call `sqlite3_errmsg` to find out what the error is.

Comment: I used sqlite3_errmsg and it returns:near "SELECT": syntax error

Comment: But the query is right: const char *sql="SELECT name FROM mydb";

Comment: Are you sure? Is `mydb` a table? Does it exist? If so, is `name` a column of that table?